# Docker custom MongoDb Ubuntu image is switching /data/db ownership in entrypoint

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I'm currently migrating our custom MongoDb from Alpine to Ubuntu since they dropped support for MongoDb a while ago. However I'm running into permission problems - specifically, I get this error when starting mongod: `exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating`

This is a pretty self-explanatory error, however, I'm at a loss here why it happens. I've tested the /data/db permissions in the Dockerfile with `ls -l /data` where its completely fine and as expected: `drwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb 4096 Jun 25 13:04 db`.
However, I also tested in the entry point.sh, again with `ls -l /data` and the permissions change for some reason to this: `drwxr-xr-x 5 _apt root 12288 Jun 25 11:56 db`, which explains the read-only error.

I have no idea what could cause this, what am I doing wrong? It seems to be related to Ubuntu maybe because this exact code works fine with the `alpine:3.9.6` image (with the installation part changed to APK and bash to sh obviously)

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# We use Ubuntu here because Alpine dropped support for MongoDB
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# Add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN groupadd -r mongodb && useradd -r -g mongodb mongodb

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg build-essential python3 python3-pip wget \
  && pip3 install pymongo flask requests

# Install mongodb (DEBIAN_FRONTEND because tzdata package is interactive)
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
  && wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y mongodb-org

# Create database directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/logs /data/db /data/config /data/backups /home/mongodb
RUN touch /home/mongodb/py.log
RUN chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/logs /data/db /data/config /data/backups /home/mongodb

# Add listener for replica set initiation
COPY listener.py /
COPY mongorestore.sh /
COPY mongodump.sh /

# Switch to non-root user
USER mongodb

# Entrypoint
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here is my entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Get keyfile from mounted secret (must be copied to location with write perms)
cp /run/secrets/mongo-keyfile /data/config/keyfile
chmod 400 /data/config/keyfile

# Run mongod without replica set, so it resets any existing config
mongod --fork --logpath /data/fork.log
mongo local --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
mongod --shutdown

# Run http listener for rs.initiate() calls and admin creation
nohup python3 -u /listener.py > ~/py.log &

# Run replica mongod instance
mongod --replSet my_project --keyFile /data/config/keyfile --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

And here is the service in my compose file:

```
  mongo:
    image: my_mongo_image
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - engine.labels.mongo == true
    networks:
      - app
    secrets:
      - mongo-keyfile
      - mongo-admin-pwd
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
      - mongo_backup:/data/backups
    logging:
      options:
        max-file: 5
        max-size: 10m
```

Comment: So you have a point in image build/starteup where permissions are crrect, and a point where they are wrong? Identify the line that is changing the permissions.

Comment: @D.SM I tried. when building the Docker image it has correct permissions until the end, and the incorrect permissions are already there before doing anything in the entrypoint

Comment: Something boot-related then? Grep `/data` in `/etc` to see what might be touching it.

Comment: Why are trying to bundle all your stuff into a single container? The idea of containers is you just stand up a mongo container on its own and link to it from your python container/other services/etc.

Comment: @D.SM nothing there. I've thought if its related to being a mounted volume, but so far it looks like everything is fine

Comment: @BellyBuster that python is there so the container can communicate with the controller

Comment: You are running the image you are building, yes? Consider bundling up your code into a github repo.

Comment: Yeah I'm running the image im building..